# Cordova and AngularJS cookies don't work

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cookies

I am working on a Cordova app developed with AngularJS.

I find that $cookies is not working in an Cordova/Phonegap app since the pages are served as a file URL. In an normal desktop browser it is also not working if you serve the pages from the filesystem - it's WORKING when served via a server or localhost.

So I get to the assumption that angular $cookies don't work for Cordova apps. 
Maybe theres a workaround for that? I just don't know, maybe someone nows an answer.

Comment: I just decided to use AngularJS $localStore alternatively and it works out of the box. The API is nearly the same with -getItem("...") and -setItem("...", "...") methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova not allows to use cookies
but you can easily move them to localStorage

try: `bower install angular-cookies-mirror`